# Unable to access variable value inside nested if statement in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script that takes advantage of libvirt hooks to set the vlan on the vm is connected to (using openvswitch). The challenge however is using the portAssigned variable inside the nested if statement, everything I've tried so far has failed. I can see the variable outside the if statement but within it, it is empty, however the portNumber variable works fine, how do I pass in $portAssigned variable to the inside if statement?

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.8(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

```
#!/bin/bash

portNumber=$(cut -d "_" -f2 <<< "$1")
domainXML=`cat /dev/stdin`
portAssigned=`echo "$domainXML" |  xmllint --xpath 'string(//domain/devices/interface[@type="bridge"]/target/@dev)' -`
DATE=$(date)
echo $domainXML | tee /home/generic_vm/domainXML.txt
echo $portAssigned | tee -a /home/generic_vm/domainXML.txt

if [ "$1" = "gene01_16" ]; then
  if [ "$2" = "prepare" ]; then
    echo "True" > /home/generic_vm/libvirt_hook.txt
    ovs-vsctl set port $portAssigned tag=$portNumber
    echo "Creating port in Openvswitch bridge for vm: $1, tag: ${portNumber}, portname: $portAssigned at ${DATE}" | tee -a /home/generic_vm/libvirt_hook.txt
  fi
elif [ "$1" = "gene01_16" ]; then
  if [ "$2" = "release" ]; then
    ovs-vsctl del-port br0 $portAssigned
    echo "Deleting port in Openvswitch bridge for vm: ${vm}, portname: $portAssigned at ${DATE}" | tee -a /home/generic_vm/libvirt_hook.txt
  fi
fi
```

```
$ cat domainXML.txt 
<domain type='kvm' id='88'> <name>gene01_16</name> <uuid>d1876d79-7fea-42b1-bd27-62a71809afaa</uuid> <memory unit='KiB'>524288</memory> <currentMemory unit='KiB'>524288</currentMemory> <vcpu placement='static'>1</vcpu> <resource> <partition>/machine</partition> </resource> <os> <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-impish'>hvm</type> <boot dev='hd'/> </os> <features> <acpi/> <apic/> <pae/> </features> <cpu mode='host-passthrough' check='none' migratable='on'/> <clock offset='utc'/> <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff> <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot> <on_crash>destroy</on_crash> <devices> <emulator>/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator> <disk type='file' device='cdrom'> <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/> <source file='/mnt/sdadisk/default/commoninit.iso' index='1'/> <backingStore/> <target dev='hdd' bus='ide'/> <readonly/> <alias name='ide0-1-1'/> <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='1'/> </disk> <controller type='usb' index='0' model='piix3-uhci'> <alias name='usb'/> <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/> </controller> <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pci-root'> <alias name='pci.0'/> </controller> <controller type='ide' index='0'> <alias name='ide'/> <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/> </controller> <controller type='virtio-serial' index='0'> <alias name='virtio-serial0'/> <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x04' function='0x0'/> </controller> <interface type='bridge'> <mac address='52:54:00:d2:2a:3a'/> <source network='br0' portid='acafb864-bcdb-4151-a3c7-40cb775f3a97' bridge='br0'/> <virtualport type='openvswitch'> <parameters interfaceid='bc652b84-773f-4924-a231-7151c01a9651'/> </virtualport> <target dev='vnet48'/> <model type='virtio'/> <alias name='net0'/> <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/> </interface> <channel type='unix'> <source mode='bind' path='/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/channel/target/domain-88-gene01_16/org.qemu.guest_agent.0'/> <target type='virtio' name='org.qemu.guest_agent.0' state='disconnected'/> <alias name='channel0'/> <address type='virtio-serial' controller='0' bus='0' port='1'/> </channel> <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'> <alias name='input0'/> </input> <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'> <alias name='input1'/> </input> <graphics type='spice' port='5906' autoport='yes' listen='127.0.0.1'> <listen type='address' address='127.0.0.1'/> </graphics> <audio id='1' type='spice'/> <video> <model type='cirrus' vram='16384' heads='1' primary='yes'/> <alias name='video0'/> <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x02' function='0x0'/> </video> <memballoon model='virtio'> <alias name='balloon0'/> <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x05' function='0x0'/> </memballoon> <rng model='virtio'> <backend model='random'>/dev/urandom</backend> <alias name='rng0'/> <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x06' function='0x0'/> </rng> </devices> <seclabel type='dynamic' model='apparmor' relabel='yes'> <label>libvirt-d1876d79-7fea-42b1-bd27-62a71809afaa</label> <imagelabel>libvirt-d1876d79-7fea-42b1-bd27-62a71809afaa</imagelabel> </seclabel> <seclabel type='dynamic' model='dac' relabel='yes'> <label>+64055:+108</label> <imagelabel>+64055:+108</imagelabel> </seclabel> </domain>
vnet48
```

Comment: Any variable should work fine inside an if loop. You could always check the content via `bash -x` or a simple `echo`. Note that you should always quote a variable with double quotes.

Comment: I don't see anything here that'd cause trouble with the `portAssigned` variable (although `vm` is used without being set). I second the recommendation of running the script with `bash -x` (or adding `set -x` at the beginning of the script) to get an execution trace. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) has a few good recommendations (which you should follow), but none that I'd expect to cause trouble with `portAssigned`.

Comment: I did run the script through shellcheck.net and made the suggested corrections but that didn't change the outcome, adding `set -x` does not return anything, however, I can see `portAssigned` in `domainXML.txt` but do not see it in `libvirt_hook.txt`, rather it's empty; `echo "$portAssigned" | tee /home/generic_vm/libvirt_hook.txt` returns an empty file, I tried adding a wait if maybe the `if` statements were executing earlier (reading up on subshells) but that didn't help. I can't seem to be able to use the variable inside the nested if block.

Comment: What do you mean "`set -x` does not return anything" -- do you mean it didn't print *anything*, or that it didn't clarify the problem? It should send an execution trace to stderr, which will at least clarify exactly what execution path is being taken.

Comment: It didn't print anything (so didn't clarify the problem I guess). I do see the variable if used outside the if expression but inside the if statement(s), it is empty.

Comment: Try simplifying your script to isolate the problem. If you can post the simplest script that exhibits the problem, then we might be able to see the issue quickly. Also. put `set -x` near the top of the script before running it.